# jQuery animation effects do not work in Safari

Tags: jquery, animation, safari

I've been pulling my hair out on this one.

I have been using jQuery to fade elements in on page load. Everything works elsewhere except for in **Safari 3 on Windows.**

Basically actions like .fadeIn, .animation don't work but .show and .css do.

EDIT: I have created a barebones example. The below webpage does not fade out or in as intended in Safari 3 for Windows...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <!-- Meta data -->
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Web Designer - Luke Franklin - Bellingen, Coffs Harbour, Mid North Coast</title>


    <!-- Third party js -->
    <script src="files/js/jquery-1.6.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <!-- Custom js -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(window).load(function() {
            alert('Run test...');
            $('#test').fadeOut('slow');
            $('#test').fadeIn('slow');
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1 id="test">Hi</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How is #header declared, does it have a height and width specified in css or text in it ?

Comment: Works perfectly [over here](http://jsfiddle.net/tkty3/) (although the CSS is placed in the CSS file, but that doesn't matter). Are you sure you're describing the problem correct (tested with Safari 5 on Windows 7)?

Comment: What jQuery version? Safari for Windows or Mac?

Comment: Good question, but Yes and Yes. In fact I have tried this on many different elements. Animations don't work period.

Comment: jQuery 1.6.1 with Safari 3 on Windows XP.

Comment: Check out: http://www.LukeFranklin.com

Comment: I tried it with all CSS removed so nothing conflicting there....

Answer (score 0):

I verified in safari 5.1 and it is working fine.

My suggestion is,

Write **css** code for #header as `display:none`

and then try with `$('#header').fadeIn('slow');`

Comment: I'm trying to avoid setting the elements hidden in CSS but I will try it just to see if it makes any difference.

Comment: CSS does not appear to be conflicting.

Answer (score 0):

Strangely, everything that wasn't working before started working after restarting Safari once more.

I'm at a loss for what was going on. It appears it's not only IE that that throws curve balls sometimes.